# Determine HTTPS status and set Header in a single line

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, http-headers

I wish to set a response header in `.htaccess` but only when the site is loaded over HTTPS:

```
Header set MyHeader "%D %t" "%{HTTPS:on}"
# Error: Unknown parameter: %{HTTPS:on}

Header set MyHeader "%D %t" "expr=%{HTTPS:on}"
# Error: syntax error, unexpected $end: Function 'HTTPS' does not exist

Header set MyHeader "%D %t" "expr=%{HTTPS}==on"    
# Error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting '('
```

`HTTPS` is listed as [a variable here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/expr.html)

PS: I'm having a really hard time understanding how [Apache expressions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/expr.html) work so if anyone has come across a simple introduction with good examples, please share.

Comment: Why the downvote? Did I break a rule?

Answer (score 2):

Use an `<If>` clause, it should work in `.htaccess`:

```
<If "%{HTTPS} == 'on'">
    Header set MyHeader "%D %t"
</If>
```

Reference:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if

Comment: Hi Jonah. Thanks, +1. I got it to work in a single line as the title requested. I just needed to use my last rule from the OP but replace `on` with `'on'`